# Repeated Measures Ancova In R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, ancova

I apologize if I am not being very clear, I have basic knowledge in statistics! I am trying to analyse my data but I am unsure if repeated measures ancova is the way to go. I have a variable named "A" measured in three different conditions "1", "2" and "3" (the sample size between groups is unequal). I also have a continues covariate measured just once in the first moment.

My R code until now is:

```r
Rmancova <- aov(A ~ condition * moment * covariate + error(id/moment)
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated it as I am very unsure!

I did try `ezAnova` in R but it didn't help me as it doesn't incorporate covariates yet.

Comment: ANOVA with repeated measures through aov is quite limited, a mixed model is a better alternative.

Comment: Also consider generalized least squares.  If you are unsure of residuals being normally distributed consider [ordinal semi parametric models](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).